# [ReactNative]DrawerLayoutAndroid behaves strangely after using stack navigator

Tags: android, react-native, drawerlayout

I am making an android app using react native.

I created a drawer on the main page via **DrawerLayoutAndroid** and applied it to **ref={}** using useRef .

I made it possible to open the drawer with **ref.current.openDrawer();** on certain buttons.

It works fine when running the app for the first time, but when you return to the main page after moving the screen using the stack navigation and press the button, it doesn't work well.

The screen just darkens and the drawer doesn't appear.

Works with the swipe gesture still works fine.

Are any of you experiencing the same problem as me?

To simplify my code, it looks like this:

```
const Main = ({navigation}) => {
  const drawer = useRef(null);

  return(
    <DrawerLayoutAndroid
      ref={drawer}
      drawerWidth={300}
      drawerPosition={'left'}
      renderNavigationView={() => <MainDrawer />}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => drawer.current.openDrawer()} />
    </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
  );
}
```

Version information is as follows.

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow": "^7.18.6",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.3",
    "@flarelane/react-native-sdk": "^1.0.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.7",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "dependencies": "^0.0.1",
    "fbjs": "^3.0.4",
    "iamport-react-native": "^2.0.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "peer": "^0.6.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-fade-in-out": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-send-intent": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.6.6",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.22.3",
    "recoil": "^0.7.3",
    "resolve-url": "^0.2.1",
    "source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.9",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had completely same problem before. I think DrawerLayoutAndroid is not compabilitable with stack navigator. I recommend DrawerNavigator in @react-navigation/drawer.
Please reference following links.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator